# Silverlight Security Issue Help - Debugging resource strings are unavailable.

Tags: wcf, silverlight, security, iis

I hosted silverlight application iis and that can be accessed in multiple ways..

When I access using Qualified name of server IP address IT WORKS fine:
http://[QUALIFIEDNAME]/WebUAT/App.aspx

When I access using IP address like below:
http://[IPADDRESS]/WebUAT/App.aspx

It gives error below:

```
[Async_ExceptionOccurred]

Arguments: 

    Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.20913.00&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred StackTrace :    at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these,

(i) Try to use fiddler and find the request which is making crossdomainpolicy xml request.

(ii)Check whether it is failing, if so add the crossdomain and clientaccesspolicy to the root folder of your Application

(iii)Check whether the service which is invoked by your application is blocked by firewall.